# Сборка ANGLE под x86

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017

Собираю [ANGLE](https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle) в студии VS2017, под windows, по [инструкции](https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle/+/master/doc/DevSetup.md). Задаю конфигурацию x86 (32bit) и генерирую проект для студии с помощью:

```
gn gen out/Debug --args="is_clang=false is_debug=true target_cpu=\"x86\""
scripts\msvs_projects.py
```

Но в итоговом проекте студии, свойство Target Machine оказывается установленным в MachineX64 (/MACHINE:X64).

Как правильно сгенерировать студийный проект для сборки ANGLE под 32-х битные системы?

Comment: Замечание "For compatibility reasons all configurations are listed as 64-bits." наводит на мысль, что такое не поддерживается.

Comment: @VTT прочитал это как все конфигурации (включая 32-х битные) будут обозначены как 64-битные в списке конфигураций студии. Надеюсь, что все таки можно как-то собирать, ведь есть ключ target_cpu=x86, и firefox работающий в 32-х битных windows (использующий angle для рендера webgl).

Comment: А просто переключить машину на 32 бит не вариант? Там наверняка все равно придется подкручивать настройки проекта.

Comment: @VTT на крайний случай так и сделаю, пока опасаюсь, что кроме установки Target Machine для 32-х систем, возможно, какие-то другие настройки меняются (например выставляются #define).